# Liferay Action Hook: how to specify a tiles redirect?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I create a Liferay 6.2 hook by following official documentation, and everything works fine.

Now I need that, in the render phase and under several conditions, my user will be redirect to a specific tiles.

Original Liferay `render` method says:

```
return actionMapping.findForward("portlet.journal.error");
```

By the way in my class (extending `BaseStrutsPortletAction`) the `render` method can't access to any `actionMapping` instance.

So... how can I obtain the same behaviour in my class?

My code says:

```
    @Override
    public String render(
            StrutsPortletAction originalStrutsPortletAction,
            PortletConfig portletConfig, RenderRequest renderRequest,
            RenderResponse renderResponse)
        throws Exception {

        Boolean myCondition = .......;

        if (myCondition) {
            // WHAT SHOULD I DO HERE?
            //return actionMapping.findForward("portlet.journal.error");
        }
        return originalStrutsPortletAction.render(
            null, portletConfig, renderRequest, renderResponse);

    }
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is to return the forward name.

Instead of `actionMapping.findForward("portlet.journal.error")`, return just `"portlet.journal.error"`.

`BaseStrutsPortletAction#render` method is called from [`com.liferay.portal.struts.PortletActionAdapter#render`](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/master/portal-impl/src/com/liferay/portal/struts/PortletActionAdapter.java), which uses the result to call `actionMapping.findForward(...)`.

Comment: This has been my first attempt, but it doesn't seem to be a working solution, because I got an empty page... After your answer I am starting to doubt that the empty page is due to a JSP issue and not to a Struts dispatching problem... I'll let you know...

Comment: Yes, my problem was due to a JSP issue... so your solution is ok. Thanks